# Was Asset Optimizer's optimized.min having multiple language version intentional?

Tags: sxa

Last night we encountered a yellow page that reads `"Unrecognizable Guid format"` and upon investigating, we found out that the `web DB` has an optimized min that has an `English (United States) version` but no `English (region) version` - which is the language our `SXA site` currently resides. So we `republished` the `Theme` and the yellow page is no longer.

Upon closer inspection, `optimized.min` has a version for each language possible. Was this intentional? Is there a way to disable this perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there was an *intention* to have this effect, it sounds just like a side effect of the CSS file being an `Item` in Sitecore. Unless you have language fallback enabled, trying to request any item that doesn't have a version in the specific language you are targeting will result in an error or an empty item depending on your config settings.

If you look at the `Optimized File` template, you see that its using `unversioned` media, so the `Media` object is marked as shared across languages, you can't have a unique version per language. But the *item* would need to have a version in the specified language to be able to get access to the media in that item.